# background wrapper issues

Tags: background, wrapper, gradient

I have been so frustrated with my site, at some point my background disappeared and i must be blind because i cant figure out how to get it back..

My website is here http://www.allramhosting.com/smyrnainlet

What i am looking for help with is id="section_wrapper" - that big white background you see...

somehow i lost the black background gradient that i made for that wrapper and its just giving my whole page a white background...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `float: left;` to section_wrapper. It fixed the issue here. It may not be the proper solution but i think you will figure out the problem using that. section_wrapper's height becomes 0 at your current site.

Note that it works with IE9 in any case.

Comment: well you did point me to the reason it wasnt working, i had to add a few clear floats that i forgot to add - thanks!